# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead, any solution?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new using Machine Learning and I am trying to predict the price of the stocks in 30 days.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymysql as MySQLdb
import numpy as np 
import sqlalchemy
import datetime
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

forecast_out = int(30) 
df['Prediction'] = df[['LastPrice']].shift(-forecast_out)
df['Prediction'].fillna(0)
X = np.array(df['Prediction'].fillna(0))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X_forecast = X[-forecast_out:] 
X = X[:-forecast_out]
y = np.array(df['Prediction'].fillna(0))
y = y[:-forecast_out]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test.reshape(-1,1)

# Training
clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
# Testing
confidence = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print("confidence: ", confidence)
forecast_prediction = clf.predict(X_forecast)
print(forecast_prediction)
```

I got this error:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
>
> ```
> array=[-0.46939923 -0.47076913 -0.47004993 ... -0.42782272  3.07433019 -0.46573474].
> ```
>
> Reshape your data either using
>
> `array.reshape(-1, 1)` if your data has a single feature
>   or
>   `array.reshape(1, -1)` if it contains a single sample.

Comment: `Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.` The error message tells you what to do.

Comment: Check the `dtype` as well.

Comment: i do it but is not working. See : X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test.reshape(-1,1)

Comment: Why do some people make a learning process so hard. All you did, Paritosh Singh was respond with the information that was already given. If your not going to help someone learn then why answer the question at all? just to make your numbers look good?

Answer (score 0):

It's expecting a 2D Array when you're only passing in a 1D Array. You can solve this by putting another set of brackets around where you're getting the probelm. For example

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
Foo(x)
```

If that throws the error, you could just do

```
Foo([x])
```

Comment: It won't solve the problem in this case, as the error message suggests you need to reshape.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).